# Windows task keeps running if called program throws exception?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

So I have a scheduled task that I am running on demand.

Is there a way to force a task to end if an error occurs?

When it runs successful, the status does not update on its own, I have to refresh manually.  However, when the called program throws exceptions, the task stays in the running state.  It would seem that I want it to simply stop and log the exception.

In my powershell script I am calling a web api method on a development server. Like this.  Note the exception handling is only trying to capture any issues with the script invoking the web request, not the web api itself.  The web app has its own exception handling & logging.

```
try {
    $order_api = "http://dev-server.testserver.com/api/orderpipeline/Runfolder";
    $order_response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $order_api -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body $jsonParams -TimeoutSec 10000;
}
catch{
        # Capture exception detail 
        $err_message =  $_.Exception | format-list -force | Out-String;     
        $log_message = $PSCommandPath + "`r`n" + " Something went wrong trying to invoke web request api, exception follows: " +  "`r`n" + $err_message;

        # Write to application event log
        New-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Order pipeline Script”
        Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Order pipeline Script” –EntryType Error –EventID 1  –Message $log_message
}}
```

I am logging the exception within the web app, so when there is an exception, I noticed that the task was still running and I had to force it to stop.  This is not something I really want to do on a production system.

How can I force the task to stop if the called program encounters an exception?

One thing Im also doing within the powershell script is using try

Comment: Is that the entire script used in the task? I ask because as-is (aside from that extra closing brace, perhaps) this appears that it should exit just fine on error. One thing to consider (may not be related to your problem) is that if you catch the exception, and don't re-throw it, the task will probably end with a "success" code, even if Invoke-Webrequest throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I force the task to stop if the called program encounters an exception?**

Based on the logic you provided in your question, you could just place a [Break](https://ss64.com/ps/break.html) within the [Catch](https://ss64.com/ps/try.html) block to tell the script to stop executing when it throws an exception.

### Example Syntax

```
try 
{
    $order_api = "http://dev-server.testserver.com/api/orderpipeline/Runfolder";
    $order_response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $order_api -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body $jsonParams -TimeoutSec 10000;
}
catch
{
    # Capture exception detail 
    $err_message =  $_.Exception | format-list -force | Out-String;     
    $log_message = $PSCommandPath + "`r`n" + " Something went wrong trying to invoke web request api, exception follows: " +  "`r`n" + $err_message;

    # Write to application event log
    New-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Order pipeline Script”
    Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source “Order pipeline Script” –EntryType Error –EventID 1  –Message $log_message
    break
}
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Break](https://ss64.com/ps/break.html)
- [Try {...} Catch {...} Finally {...}](https://ss64.com/ps/try.html)